# How to handle NULL for Django DB Function Concat?

Tags: django, django-models

I want the query set to return concatenated string for address. I'm currently writing code like this:

```
queryset = Place.objects.annotate(
        place_address= Concat('address__city', Value(', '),'address__state__name'))
     )
```

It return fine when city and state field is not empty. But it does not handle null value with this solution where the result could ended up:

```
"Kuala Lumpur, " OR ", Selangor" OR ", "
```

Is there a way to skip adding delimiter when the field in front is null? Thanks.

Comment: did you used Coalesc  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Django built-in Case-When conditions.

link to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

```
from django.db.models import Value, Case, When

queryset = Place.objects.annotate(
    place_address=Concat(
        'address__city',
        Case(
            When(
                address__city__isnull=True,
                then=Value('')
            ),
            When(
                address__state__name__isnull=True,
                then=Value('')
            ),
            default=Value(', ')
        ),
        'address__state__name'
    )
)
```